# Disable fade for Bootstrap modal on tablet

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried searching but haven't found any answers to this question. Wondering if there is a way to disable the fade/fade in only on tablets. I really like the effect but it's a bit glitchy on tablets, mobile devices. So, wondering if I can do some sort of @media or add some javascript/jQuery to disable the feature on tablets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible by just overriding bootstrap CSS in appropriate media query.

Example: (Bootstrap 3.0.2)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 979px) {

  /* Modal wrapper */
  .modal.fade {
    opacity: 1;
   }

  /* Modal dialog */
  .modal.fade .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
        -ms-transform: translate(0,0);
            transform: translate(0,0);
  }

  /* Semi-transparent backdrop */
  .modal-backdrop.fade {
    opacity: .5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  }
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/tigran_io/pen/Lcdva)

Comment: Hello Tigran Petrossian. Thank you very much for your response! Unfortunately I am unable to get this to work. However, might be because I'm running an older version of Bootstrap, v2.2.1. Sorry, I didn't specify version in my original post. I tried to use your idea with changes directed to to this older version but no luck. Do you know if it's possible with older versions and, if so, any specifics on how? Thanks again, much appreciated.